# Not supported (tabular model 1200 or higher required)

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools, ssas-tabular

I get the following error in Visual Studio when I'm working with SSAS Tabular project.

"Not supported (tabular model 1200 or higher required)"
[image]

- SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition
- Visual Studio 2015

Comment: I guess that Tabular Model Explorer pane isn't supported on older models. Ignore that and flip to the Solution Explorer pane.

Comment: Looks like that was the answer. Thanks @GregGalloway

Answer (score -1):

Install sql server management studio 2016,
after that install sql server data tool which automatically install visual studio
this will solve your problem